# Class.getPackage() within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, java-8

The recommended way to extract the version from a manifest is using `getPackage().getImplementationVersion()` to extract it.

But this doesn't seem to work when debugging inside Eclipse; I'm guessing because building a jar is an external Ant operation and Eclipse knows nothing about jar files and manifests.

So how can I write code that works inside and outside Eclipse to find the version without storing it in multiple locations? The only way I've come up with is to write a properties file, then read it in the Ant build step to create the manifest and read it directly in java to extract the VERSION property.

Or is there some better way? [Note: Java 8]

Comment: Do you have `Implementation-Version` property in your Manifest ?

Comment: Yes. And it works when I run the .jar, just not within Eclipse.

Comment: Add your `META-INF` folder under `src` then load the `MANIFEST.MF` file as properties file. Then you'll be able to get all properties by using their property name.